# Is it okay to use time-stamp as an int for a long lasting software?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, php, c++

In languages like c++ , the max integer value is 2147483647 (32 bit max). The current time stamp is around 1485414545. If we use time-stamp as an int, is there a possibility for a software to have a bug in few years, when the time-stamp gets bigger than 32 bit max value?

It will take around 20 years (2147483647-1485414545)/(3600*24*365) , is there a possibility that most of the software with time-stamps as integers would break?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Is there *any* possibility that the software will be used in 20 years? If yes, use a 64-bit integer. If you're unsure, use a 64-bit integer.

Comment: I'm not sure how other programming languages handle it, but Java uses long (64-bit integer) for timestamps by default.

Comment: Even going for an unsigned int would add many decades.

Comment: Or use one of the provided time types for the relevant language.

Comment: By the way, two's complement requires 1 bit for *signed* integers.  Integers are signed in C++ (such as int).  You can increase the range by using *unsigned* numbers.

Comment: You forgot some languages, such as Ada, Pascal, Fortran, Python, Ruby, Cobol, BASIC and Forth.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how to use unsigned numbers ? how to define them ? , & yeah I should have added those languages as well , but I think python don't have this problem :)

Comment: In C++, you use the prefix "unsigned".  As you can see, languages are different in this respect.  Which language are you writing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a 64-bit integer... So in any case you are right!

Comment: Sure ! thank you :)